# Inicio sesión en php

Tags: php, sesiones

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario de inicio de sesión en php. Lo que pretendo es que el usuario su user y si es el registrado previamente en la base de datos que me dirija automaticamente a una página index.php determinada. No consigo hacerlo funcionar.

Dejo mi código

```
 <?php
session_start(); //Iniciamos o Continuamos la sesion
if (isset($_POST['user'])) //Si llego un Nickname via el formulario lo grabamos en la Sesion
if (isset($_POST['pass'])) //Si llego un Nickname via el formulario lo grabamos en la Sesion
{
    $_SESSION['nickname'] = $_POST['user']; //Nickname Grabado
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['pass']; //Nickname Grabado
}
if ($_SESSION['nickname']) //Si hay un nickname en la sesion actual, creamos una variable que será mostrada

<a href='index.php'></a>;
}
?>
<html>
<form class='formLogin' name='login' action='' method='post'>
    <h2>Lectureka! Acceso al Sistema</h2>
    <label>Usuario:</label><input type='text' name='user' placeholder='Introduzca usuario' /><br>   
    <label>Contraseña:</label><input type='password' name='pass' placeholder='Introduzca contraseña' value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['nickname'];?>" /><br>
    <input type='submit'  class='btn' value='Entrar'  /> <a href='index.php' >
        <a href='' class='btn'>Crear una cuenta</a>
</form>     
    <head>
        <title>Libreria</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="estilos/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div class="clear"></div>                
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="columna">
                <ul>
                    <li>Aviso legal</li>
                    <li>Política de privacidad</li>
                </ul>                    
            </div>

            <div class="columna derecha">
                <p>Tu librería online
                </p>                    
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>    
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: pero no estas haciendo la consulta a la base de datos, deberias tomar el user y password e irlos a buscar a la base de datos y si estan correcto crear la sesion y redigirlo a index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conexion a la Base:

```
<?php
//servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","password","nombre_base"); 

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}


 //Primero verifica si existe la sesion:

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

 //sino entoces buscamos los datos en a BD
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $error = '';

    $sql = "SELECT id, id_tipo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' 
        AND password = '$password'";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['id_tipo'];

        header("location: index.php");
        } else {
        $error = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
    }
}
```

Comment: Me da este error en    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
   $rows = $result->num_rows; Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\Xampp\htdocs\\register.php on line 19

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\Xampp\htdocs\\register.php on line 19

Comment: que gestor de base de datos usas?

Comment: Estoy utilizando phpmyadmin

Comment: ok agregue la conexion a la base al inicio de la respuesta

Comment: /*
        define("SERVIDOR", "localhost");
        define("USUARIO", "root");
        define("CONTRASENA", "");
        define("BASEDATOS", "lecture");

        $enlaceBD = mysqli_connect( SERVIDOR,USUARIO, CONTRASENA, BASEDATOS);

        $enlaceBD->set_charset("utf8");
    
        if( !$enlaceBD )
        {
            echo "La conexión no se ha podido establecer";
            exit();
        }*/
?>

Comment: lo he probado y funciona

Comment: pues a mi me da el error ese que he comentado